# Cannot view website (running in glassfish home server / router ports are forwarded)

Tags: glassfish, portforwarding

I would like to show the website I have made to a friend. But I just can't seem to get the website available to the rest of the web.

Ok, so the details are:

- I created a jsp website
- It is hosted on GlassFish v3
- I forwarded port 8080 to the pc hosting GlassFish (Tested with [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/))

With all this as is, I don't know what else to do. I am 'n newbie web developer and I have tried the internet for answers but no luck. If anyone can assist, it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have a dyndns.org ddns that I am using. I also tried using my external IP, but to no avail.

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you trying to access the site (by IP address or a domain name)? Can you provide some more info?

Comment: I used a ddns and also tried external ip:   123.123.123.123:8080/isms/login.jsp  OR   www.abc.com:8080/isms/login/jsp

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Glassfish is listening on the PC's real IP address, i.e. not on 127.0.0.1 (localhost). If it's running on localhost, then you'll be able to see it from the same machine, but not from anywhere else.

I'm not a glassfish user, though, so I can't tell you how to go about changing it.

Comment: Thanks, but I did change the server to listen on the pc's lan ip